# javascript printing to previous line

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of code that requires printing underscores but to the line above it, how would i do this? I'm not sure how to print the underscore to the previous line, not much experience with javascript. thanks!

```
var landscape = function() {
  var result = "";
  var flat = function(size) {
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
      result +=  "_";
  };
  var hill = function(size) {
    result += " /";
    for (var count = 0; count < size; count++)
      result += ""+
                "_";
    result += " \\";
  };


  //BUILD SCRIPT
  flat(3)
  hill(4);
  flat(6);
  hill(1);
  flat(1);
  //END SCRIPT
  return result;

it makes this ___ /____ \______ /_ \_`enter code here`enter code here`
and i want this
    _____    ___
___/     \__/   \____/\_
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep track of the two lines separately and then concatenate them just before returning the result.

JS:

```
function landscape() {
    var resultTop = '';
    var resultBottom = '';

    function hill(size) {
        resultTop += ' ';
        resultBottom += '/';
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            resultTop += '_';
            resultBottom += ' ';
        }
        resultTop += ' ';
        resultBottom += '\\';
    }

    function flat(size) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            resultTop += ' ';
            resultBottom += '_';
        }
    }

    flat(3);
    hill(4);
    flat(6);
    hill(1);
    flat(1);

    var result = resultTop + '<br/>' + resultBottom;
    return result;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb5g12mm/).

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to print a unicode character that draws a line on top. Turns out there is such a character: the [Upper One-eighth Block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2594/index.htm)

It's `"\u2594"` in unicode escape or `&#9620;` as HTML entity or you can simply copy/paste the literal character from the example below:

```
____/▔▔▔▔\____/▔▔\___
```